# Httpclient MethodNotAllowed 405 for Getting remote file size

Tags: c#, httpclient, desktop-application, .net-framework-version

Could someone help me. I'm getting a little problem with requesting Head method to get the file size.
If I changed the method to GET, I can get the length of the url. but if I do Head method, I'm getting error "MethodNotAllowed 405". Hopefully someone can help me.
because Get method is so slow and takes time to get the bytes.
Thank you so much.

Here's my code:

```
public static async void TEST()
{
    var urls = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\MARK\Desktop\TEST\test.txt");
    var bytes = await Task.Run(() => GetRemoteFileSize(urls));
    var fileSize = FormatFileSize(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(fileSize);
}

private const string UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36";
private static readonly HttpClientHandler hander = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = null,
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    UseProxy = false,
};
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(hander);


public static async Task<long> GetRemoteFileSize(string[] urls, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    long sum = 0;
    long localSum = 0;

    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        tasks.Add(GetTotalBytes(url, ct));
    }

    await Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray());
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        localSum += Convert.ToInt32(task.Result);
    }
    return Interlocked.Add(ref sum, localSum);
}
private static async Task<string> GetTotalBytes(string url, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri))
    {
        request.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UA);
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, ct).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException($"Error occured: {statusCode} {(int)statusCode}");
            }
            return response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.ToString();
        }
    }

}

public static string FormatFileSize(long bytes)
{
    var unit = 1024;
    if (bytes < unit)
    {
        return $"{bytes} B";
    }
    var exp = (int)(Math.Log(bytes) / Math.Log(unit));
    return $"{bytes / Math.Pow(unit, exp):F2} {("KMGTPE")[exp - 1]}B";
}
```

Comment: It's not mandatory for a Web Site to answer to HEAD requests, as it's not mandatory to set the Content-Disposition header or provide the size of a file. Anyway, try with just, e.g., `var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`. The `response.Headers` is a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`. If you get the same 405, then no luck. Btw, if you set `AllowAutoRedirect = false`, you must have a good reason for it.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna try it. Thank you

Comment: I tried, and now the error is Forbidden 403 even if I set user agent.

Comment: Looks like a POST instead of a GET or the location is simply out of reach. Can you provide a URL for testing?

Comment: @Jimi here's the example url: https://pastebin.com/raw/Ap68NLhU

Comment: Those addresses both return Access Denied right away.

Comment: ah sorry I think, it's not working with other country. Only in Philippines IP